# How to filter data with method GetAll() and UnitOfWork (Repository Pattern)

Tags: c#, linq, filter, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have an initial table in the Index Get method where I query all the columns I want to display, with `GetAll()` method. Here I also load the drop-down menus where I select the parameters.

```
/********INDEX GET*********/

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
            BudgetVM = new BudgetViewModel()
            {
                FBudget = new FBudget(),

                YearsList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetYearsListForDropdown(),
                CompanyList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetCompanyListForDropDown(),
                CustomerList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetCustomerListForDropDown(),
                ProductGroupList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetProductGroupListForDropDown(),
                LicensingAreaList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetLicensingAreaListForDropDown(),
                PharmaFormList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetPharmaFormListForDropDown(),
                LedgerScenarioList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetLedgerScenarioListForDropDown(),
                CurrencyList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetCurrencyListForDropdown(),
                //Lista di tutti i record
                RecordsList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetAll(includeProperties: "ItemMaster,Customer")
            };

            return View(BudgetVM);
        
    }
```

Here is the view that will send the parameters to the Index Post method:

```
    @model SalesBudget.Models.ViewModels.BudgetViewModel
    
    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

<form method="post" asp-controller="Budget" asp-action="Index">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <br />
            <h2 class="text-primary">Filter by</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="dropdown">
                @*Parameter1: what I want to save in the db
                Parameter2: actual list of items (dropdown menu)
                Parameter3: default that I see in the dropdown
                Parameter4: classes that I want to add*@
                <!--BLOCCA IL PROGRAMMA IN DELETE-->
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FBudget.CompanyId,
                                        Model.CompanyList,
                                        "--Company--",
                                        new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="dropdown">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FBudget.CustomerId,
                                        Model.CustomerList,
                                        "--Customer--",
                                        new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="dropdown">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FBudget.Customer.LicensingArea,
                                        Model.LicensingAreaList,
                                        "--Licensing Area--",
                                        new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="dropdown">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FBudget.Year,
                                        Model.YearsList,
                                        "--Year--",
                                        new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="dropdown">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FBudget.ItemMaster.ProductGroupId,
                                        Model.ProductGroupList,
                                        "--Product Group--",
                                        new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="dropdown">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FBudget.ItemMaster.PharmaFormId,
                                        Model.PharmaFormList,
                                        "--Pharma Form--",
                                        new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="dropdown">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.FBudget.Currency,
                                        Model.CurrencyList,
                                        "--Currency--",
                                        new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="dropdown">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FBudget.LedgerTypeId,
                                        Model.LedgerScenarioList,
                                        "--Scenario--",
                                        new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Go</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<hr />


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h2 class="text-primary">Budget List</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <a asp-action="Upsert" class="btn btn-primary float-end"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; Create New Budget</a>
    </div>
</div>

<br />


<br />
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Customer
            </th>
            <th>
                Decription
            </th>
            <th>
                Curr
            </th>
            <th>
                FoC
            </th>
            <th>
                UM
            </th>
            <th>
                Price
            </th>
            <th>
                Quantity
            </th>
            <th>
                Total amount
            </th>
            <th>
                Action
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.RecordsList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer.CustomerName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemMaster.ItemDescription)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Currency)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FreeOfCharge)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitOfMeasure)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitPrice)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalAmount)
                </td>


                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Upsert" asp-route-id="@item.BudgetId">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.BudgetId">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the Index Post method in the Controller:

```
/********INDEX POST*********/

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(BudgetViewModel budget)
    {
        BudgetVM = new BudgetViewModel()
        {
            FBudget = new FBudget(),

            YearsList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetYearsListForDropdown(),
            CompanyList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetCompanyListForDropDown(),
            CustomerList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetCustomerListForDropDown(),
            ProductGroupList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetProductGroupListForDropDown(),
            LicensingAreaList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetLicensingAreaListForDropDown(),
            PharmaFormList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetPharmaFormListForDropDown(),
            LedgerScenarioList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetLedgerScenarioListForDropDown(),
            CurrencyList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetCurrencyListForDropdown(),


           //Here isd where I try to filter data
            RecordsList = _unitOfWork.Budget.GetAll(
                                                     filter: b => b.Year == budget.FBudget.Year
                                                     && b.CompanyId == budget.FBudget.CompanyId
                                                     && b.CustomerId == budget.FBudget.CustomerId
                                                     && b.Customer.LicensingArea == budget.FBudget.Customer.LicensingArea
                                                     && b.ItemMaster.ProductGroupId == budget.FBudget.ItemMaster.ProductGroupId
                                                     && b.ItemMaster.PharmaFormId == budget.FBudget.ItemMaster.PharmaFormId
                                                     && b.Currency == budget.FBudget.Currency
                                                     && b.LedgerTypeId == budget.FBudget.LedgerTypeId

                                                     , includeProperties: "ItemMaster,Customer")

        };


        //return View(budget);
        return View(BudgetVM);
}
```

Naturally with the logical operator `&&` all fields must be inserted, otherwise the query result will be empty. How can I make these parameters optional, so that if I select only one filter (dropdown) the query is made only on that field, excluding the others?

Here is the `GetAll()` method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = null)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }
        //include properties will be comma seperated
        if (includeProperties != null)
        {
            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can either use something like [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to build the filter, or build it yourself using the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace.

For example, assuming any filter properties which are not set will be `null`:

```
public static Expression<Func<Budget, bool>> BuildFilter(BudgetViewModel budget)
{
    var b = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Budget), "b");
    var filterParts = new List<Expression>();
    if (budget.FBudget.Year is {} year)
    {
        var bugetYear = Expression.Property(b, nameof(Budget.Year);
        var testYear = Expression.Constant(year);
        filterParts.Add(Expression.Equal(budgetYear, testYear));
    }
    if (budget.FBudget.CompanyId is {} companyId)
    {
        var budgetCompanyId = Expression.Property(b, nameof(Budget.CompanyId));
        var testCompanyId = Expression.Constant(companyId);
        filterParts.Add(Expression.Equal(budgetCompanyId, testCompanyId));
    }
    if (budget.FBudget.CustomerId is {} customerId)
    {
        var budgetCustomerId = Expression.Property(b, nameof(Budget.CustomerId));
        var testCustomerId = Expression.Constant(customerId);
        filterParts.Add(Expression.Equal(budgetCustomerId, testCustomerId));
    }
    if (budget.FBudget.Customer.LicensingArea is {} licensingArea)
    {
        var budgetCustomer = Expression.Property(b, nameof(Budget.Customer));
        var budgetLicensingArea = Expression.Property(budgetCustomer, nameof(Customer.LicensingArea));
        var testLicensingArea = Expression.Constant(licensingArea);
        filterParts.Add(Expression.Equal(budgetLicensingArea, testLicensingArea));
    }
    if (budget.FBudget.ItemMaster.ProductGroupId is {} productGroupId)
    {
        var budgetItemMaster = Expression.Property(b, nameof(Budget.ItemMaster));
        var budgetProductGroupId = Expression.Property(budgetItemMaster, nameof(ItemMaster.ProductGroupId));
        var testProductGroupId = Expression.Constant(productGroupId);
        filterParts.Add(Expression.Equal(budgetProductGroupId, testProductGroupId));
    }
    if (budget.FBudget.ItemMaster.PharmaFormId is {} pharmaFormId)
    {
        var budgetItemMaster = Expression.Property(b, nameof(Budget.ItemMaster));
        var budgetPharmaFormId = Expression.Property(budgetItemMaster, nameof(ItemMaster.PharmaFormId));
        var testPharmaFormId = Expression.Constant(pharmaFormId);
        filterParts.Add(Expression.Equal(budgetPharmaFormId, testPharmaFormId));
    }
    if (budget.FBudget.Currency is {} currency)
    {
        var budgetCurrency = Expression.Property(b, nameof(Budget.Currency));
        var testCurrency = Expression.Constant(currency);
        filterParts.Add(Expression.Equal(budgetCurrency, testCurrency));
    }
    if (budget.FBudget.LedgerTypeId is {} ledgerTypeId)
    {
        var budgetLedgerTypeId = Expression.Property(b, nameof(Budget.LedgerTypeId));
        var testLedgerTypeId = Expression.Constant(ledgerTypeId);
        filterParts.Add(Expression.Equal(budgetLedgerTypeId, testLedgerTypeId));
    }
    
    if (filterParts.Count == 0) return null;
    
    var body = filterParts.Aggregate(Expression.AndAlso);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Budget, bool>>(body, b);
}
```

Comment: Not too complicated for `AndAlso`? :) Everything can be done jus by chaining with `if` and `query = query.Where(..)`

Comment: Thank you. Where do you suggest to put this code? In the Controller or in the Repository as a method, and then calling it from the Controller?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv If the repository retuned `IQueryable<T>`, that would work. Since it returns `IEnumerable<T>`, you could only do that if you built the filter inside the repository; otherwise, you'll end up loading everything into memory before filtering.

Comment: @chdev Probably not in the repository - that shouldn't really know anything about your view-models. Either a method in the controller, or in a separate class, depending on whether or not you're going to use it from multiple controllers.

Comment: @RichardDeeming Ok I've impllemented the method in the Controller. Now when I try to display data, I get this error: ` Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Expression<Func<FBudget, bool>>' because 'Expression<Func<FBudget, bool>>' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'` how can I iterate through the results of the method BuilFilter()?

Comment: @chdev You pass the result of the `BuildFilter` method to the `filter` parameter of your repository's `GetAll` method.

Comment: @RichardDeeming thanks. I've implemented your solution, but the result is the same as my previous (not working as I need) solution. If I select only one filter (for example Company) and I leave the others empty (null) the query result is null, because the query would be somthing like `((((((b.Year == 0) AndAlso (b.CompanyId == 1)) AndAlso (b.CustomerId == 0)) AndAlso...` What I need is that if I select only one filter, I query all the records with this field. For example `SELECT * FROM Budget WHERE CompanyId == 1` but excluding the other filters.... any suggestions?

Comment: @chdev As I said, the assumption was that any filters which are not set would be `null`. If they're `0` instead, then you need to change the tests - eg: `if (budget.FBudget.Year is {} year && year != 0)`.

Comment: @RichardDeeming Thank you very much. Sorry for that, I'm a finishing student. Thanks!